# Bedeutung von Daumkraft

Tags: meaning, etymology, russian-to-german

Im Russischen Roman von Ilf und Petrow „Zwölf Stühle“ ist mir ein Wort aufgefallen, nämlich Domkrat (домкрат).

> <sup>„Слушайте! «Домкрат (нем. **Daumkraft**) – одна из машин для поднятия значительных тяжестей. Обыкновенный простой Д., употребляемый для поднятия экипажей и т. п., состоит из подвижной зубчатой полосы, которую захватывает шестерня, вращаемая с помощью рукоятки».”</sup>

Dies bedeutet Wagenheber, aber das ist anscheinend hier nicht wichtig. Hauptsache, dass es vom Deutschen *Daumkraft* abgeleitet worden sein soll, so der Roman selbst. Seine Bedeutung finde ich aber nirgends.

DWDS sagt beispielsweise:

> daumkraft f
>   Fundstelle: Lfg. 4 (1856), Bd. II (1860), Sp. 853, Z. 39
>   starke winde bei den schiffen. niederl. dommekracht, franz. cric, engl. handscrew.

Ein Russisches Wörterbuch sagt auch: vom Niederländischen *dommekracht*, mich interessiert aber, ob das **deutsche** Wort existiert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nach meinen Recherche kann ich sagen, dass sie eine Art von Maschine ist.

[Allgemeines Wörterbuch der Marine](https://books.google.de/books?id=m6M_AAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA447&lpg=RA1-PA447&dq=Wagenwinde%20cric%20daumkraft&source=bl&ots=stS3iYyzHD&sig=0-G73NIoNnv4etNNDyq-03DPq1g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC_N7xhMLTAhVDtBQKHSO_BfEQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Band 2) von Johann Hinrich Röding sagt;

> Eine bekannte und bey der Marine sehr nützliche Machine.

Einige Bilder von Daumkraft: [1. Bild](http://www.zeno.org/Brockhaus-1911/I/bk20988a) und [2.Bild](https://www.flickr.com/photos/53357451@N08/22027786240)

Answer (score 8):

Ich kenne das Wort aus meinem Sprachgebrauch **nicht**.

[Hier](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=124188&imageview=true) findet sich das Wort (mit einer allerdings sehr kargen Erläuterung) in einem alten Wörterbuch. Demnach sollte das Wort schon existieren.

Im [*Handbuch der praktischen Seefahrtskunde*](https://books.google.de/books?id=dAjaDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1980&lpg=PA1980&dq=daumkraft%20winde&source=bl&ots=I3tcL5Q2WH&sig=M6jkvktdqXCPIjA6PcLCCErTek8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGx42uhcLTAhWFKMAKHYLCDEIQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=daumkraft%20winde&f=false) von 1846 taucht das Wort ebenfalls auf.

Es scheint sich um einen seefahrerischen Fachbegriff zu handeln, der wie wohl viele solche Ausdrücke aus dem Niederländischen stammt bzw. mit diesem eine gemeinsame Entstehungsgeschichte hat. In der zweiten Quelle gibt es auch eine genaue Erklärung, um was es sich dabei handelt: Es scheint eine Art einfacher Wagenheber auf Basis einer Zahnstange zu sein, der schwere Lasten über geringe Höhen anheben kann.

Wikipedia kennt den Begriff *[Daumenkraft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zahnstangenwinde)* als "in Norddeutschland" verwendeten Begriff für Zahnstangenwinde (ziemlich am Ende des Artikels). Den Begriff "Daumenkraft" findet man auch an mehreren weiteren Fundstellen, hauptsächlich aus dem norddeutschen Bereich.

Die Eisenbahn hatte (und hat) durchaus ähnliche Maschinen, dort hießen diese Geräte aber grundsätzlich "Wagenheber".